# Swagger/Swashbuckle not generating Tags element at root

Tags: swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

We have Swagger setup on our .NET API (not Core) using Swashbuckle.

I'm looking at LucyBot to make a nicer looking documentation page.  Looking at their sample, their OpenAPI file has a 'tags' element at the root, which is used to split the display into groups.  Ours (/swagger/docs/v1) has no such element.  I've tried playing around with everything I can see in the SwaggerConfig.cs, but am having no luck.

Any easy way to auto generate this?  Some option, or comments, or something I'm just overlooking?

````
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "This is a demo of [LucyBot's API Documentation](http:\/\/lucybot.com) using swagger.io's Petstore server.  You can find out more about Swagger at [http:\/\/swagger.io](http:\/\/swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http:\/\/swagger.io\/irc\/).  For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization filters.\n\nTo use this documentation for your own API, visit [http:\/\/lucybot.com](http:\/\/lucybot.com)",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "Swagger Petstore",
    "termsOfService": "http:\/\/swagger.io\/terms\/",
    "contact": {
      "email": "apiteam@swagger.io"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.apache.org\/licenses\/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    }
  },
  "host": "petstore.swagger.io",
  "basePath": "\/v2",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "pet",
      "description": "Everything about your Pets",
      "externalDocs": {
        "description": "Find out more",
        "url": "http:\/\/swagger.io"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "store",
      "description": "Access to Petstore orders"
    },
    {
      "name": "user",
      "description": "Operations about user",
      "externalDocs": {
        "description": "Find out more about our store",
        "url": "http:\/\/swagger.io"
      }
    }
  ],```
````

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code swashbuckle code for the externalDocs:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerDocument.cs#L134
Good thing that is there in the definitions, but is not used anywhere...

I think your only option would be to use and IDocumentFilter and inject your missing tags.
here is an example of how to use those filters:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/5489aca0d2dd7946f5569341f621f581720d4634/Swashbuckle.Dummy.Core/SwaggerExtensions/AppendVersionToBasePath.cs